# test for node membership in pydot graph

Tags: python, graphviz, dot, pydot

pydot has a huge number of bound methods for getting and setting every little thing in a dot graph, reading and writing, you-name-it, but I can't seem to find a simple membership test.

```
>>> d = pydot.Dot()
>>> n = pydot.Node('foobar')
>>> d.add_node(n)

>>> n in d.get_nodes()
False
```

is just one of many things that didn't work. It appears that nodes, once added to a graph, acquire a new identity

```
>>> d.get_nodes()[0]
<pydot.Node object at 0x171d6b0>
>>> n
<pydot.Node object at 0x1534650>
```

Can anyone suggest a way to create a node and test to see if it's in a graph before adding it so you could do something like this:

```
d = pydot.Dot()
n = pydot.Node('foobar')
if n not in d:
    d.add_node(n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the source code, http://code.google.com/p/pydot/source/browse/trunk/pydot.py, it seems that node names are unique values, used as the keys to locate the nodes within a graph's node dictionary (though, interestingly, rather than return an error for an existing node, it simply adds the attributes of the new node to those of the existing one).

So unless you want to add an implementation of `__contains__()` to one of the classes in the `pydot.py` file that does the following, you can just do the following in your code:

```
if n.get_name() not in d.obj_dict['nodes'].keys():
    d.add_node(n)
```

Comment: Thanks @JAB. I'd come to the same conclusion. It's unsatisfying, but your solution is better than mine: `if n.get_name() not in [node.get_name() for node in d.get_node_list()]`

Comment: You could always bring this up with the creators of `pydot`. It's an open-source project, after all. ...Also, I just found out why, specifically, you were having your problem with changing identity, and why they might not want to change things. http://code.google.com/p/pydot/ "Graph, Node, Edge objects are mere proxies to the data and are created on demand."